# Failed to compile. | Module parse failed | appropriate loader

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

**The Problem:**

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/posts/Posts.jsx 18:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 5
|     }
>   }, posts?.map(function (p) {
|     return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Post, {
|       post: p,
```

When I use `npm start` it gives me the above error, I don't why

**I tried**

- Deleting babel-loader from node_modules and downgrade to 8.0.5, because before this error there was an error telling me that this react app requires babel-loader 8.0.5
- Deleing all node_modules and package-lock.json and then `npm install`

This is the **Posts.jsx**

```
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";
import React from "react";

export default function Posts({ posts = [] }) {
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      {posts?.map((p) => (
        <Post post={p} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
    "jodit-react": "^1.3.10",
    "markdown-draft-js": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in your babel and webpack config?

Comment: @RyanLe if you mean babel.config.json and webpack.config.json I don't have these files